# FLVPlayback component won't seamlessly loop

Tags: flash, loops, flvplayback, progressive-download

Everything I've tried so far with a FLVPlayback component to seemlessly loop a progressively-downloaded 15 second video has failed.  There's always a split-second pause when it's time to loop.  For the scenario, embedding video in a flash project is not an option, and the split-second pause is unacceptable.  I've tried setting autorewind to true and handling autorewind event fired by FLVplayback.  I've tried watching the playhead of the flvplayer for when It gets upwards of 99.5 percent done and seeking to 0.  My latest solution involves having two VideoPlayer instances with the same source behind the FLVPlayback component and toggling between them when it's time to loop, and there is still a seem between the end and beginning.  I've tested the video in quicktime to make sure it's not an artifact of the video.

Has anyone successfullly done this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the displeasure of grappling with this problem as well, and unfortunately there's no way to pull it off (check out this [actionscript.org](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=139698) forum post for details).  The only option at your disposal if you really need a seamless loop is to embed the FLV in your swf by putting it in the timeline, which will give you perfect results; however, you then sacrifice the ability to progressively download the video.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news!  I've always dealt with this in the past by either a) embedding my videos, if they're short enough, or b) engineering the video content so that the little hiccup isn't noticeable (e.g. using some sort of easing in the first/last few frames of the video).